# in google calendar, does multiple projects need multiple console projects?

Tags: php, google-api, google-calendar-api

i developed a sync option for a CRM system with google calendar. the system is installed in a certain domain.
i get a refresh token and access token for each user in the system and store it in the user profile.
it works great.
now a friend of mine wants that deveopment for his CRM system too (in a different URL).
Does that mean i need to open a new project for him too? or can i take refresh tokens and acess tokens extracted using the first project and copy them to the users in the other CRM system?

in short:
1. Do i need to open a new project in the developer Console for every CRM system hosted in different URL?
2. Is there a limitation to the number of projects i can open ( in case i install this CRM system in tens of businesses with different URLs)?
3. i read that i can only get 25 refresh tokens per project, what happens if the CRM system has more than 25 users? didn't find any information... do i pay Google for more? how much?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is going to end up being more of a clarification then an answer but its to long for a comment.

The point of developer console is to identify **YOUR** application.  Each application should have its own project on developer console.    If your friend wants to develop his own application then he should have is own project on developer console.

**Copying refresh token**

If your friend is using your application then he should could use your project id. Basically if the code is the same you can keep it as the same project.  If your friend does take a copy of your program for his use technically speaking you could copy the users refresh tokens, as long as he has them and your client id and client secret they will work.

But I think you may want to consider how wise that is.  Users are giving **you** access to there data, they have not given your friend access to there data.  I am not sure if this is against some privacy policy, I will have to check but IMO it should be.   You should not be sharing authentication granted to you by a user to someone else.

If it was me even if he was copying your code he should still have his own project and get his own users.

**Quota**

The main problem with sharing a project is that you will also be sharing the quota.  I am not sure what api you are accessing but you are aloud a limited number of requests per day.  If you are both using it your both eating away at the quota.

**25 refreshtoken**

That part of the documentation is a little unclear.  Its 25 refresh tokens *per user per client*.  Example: So I could authenticate your application 25 times all 25 refresh tokens will work when I authenticate you again the 26th time the oldest one will then stop working.

Your application can have an unlimited number of users.

Comment: thank you so much for replying my questions. just to clarify, i'm hosting CRM system for my friends and maybe others, only i will have access to the tokens and calendar data and console. and i will host the same CRM system code for everyone. i'm using "Calendar API". So what you are saying is that i could host an unlimited number of CRM systems with the Calendar Support, in different Domains. all of them will access the same project in developer console. each CRM system can have unlimited number of users and when i get to the Quota limit, i could open a new project and start again?

Comment: Quota limit is daily.  So it will reset the next day. I wouldn't create a new one in that instance just request that your quota limit be increased.  If you create a new one then some people would have access on one client id and others with another one it would be impossible to figure out.

Comment: Keep the same project just don't share user for CRM 1 with CRM 2, and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanky you so much :)